# Bridged Docker Container not accessible via wireguard interface

Tags: networking, docker, vpn

My Docker Host has multiple Containers running, which I want to access via my wireguard interface wg0.

They are reachable via the Interface *enp3s0* which has 192.168.0.12 but not on the wireguard Interface *wg0* with 10.8.0.4

The Containers are in a bridged Network (172.17.0.0/16) with Ports mapped to the Host listening on all Interfaces.

I can't find what's wrong with my setup.
Is maybe something wrong with the routing?

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                           NAMES
56f5793559ef        gogs/gogs:latest      "/app/gogs/docker/st…"   8 days ago          Up 19 minutes       80/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp   Gogs
ef7aabd2a54d        nextcloud:latest      "/entrypoint.sh apac…"   8 days ago          Up 19 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                                            Nextcloud
b591c364db96        mariadb:latest        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 weeks ago         Up 19 minutes       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                                          MariaDB
7a7533d05ec2        portainer/portainer   "/portainer"             2 weeks ago         Up 19 minutes       0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                                          Portainer
```

```
# netstat -tulpn | grep docker
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      30704/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      30782/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::2222                 :::*                    LISTEN      30746/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      30851/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      30733/docker-proxy
```

```
# ip -o a s
1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
1: lo    inet6 ::1/128 scope host \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0    inet 192.168.0.12/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic enp3s0\       valid_lft 599865sec preferred_lft 599865sec
2: enp3s0    inet6 2a02:810d:8800:3e38::833e/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute \       valid_lft 599865sec preferred_lft 599865sec
2: enp3s0    inet6 2a02:810d:8800:3e38:7285:c2ff:fe85:90ac/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute \       valid_lft 298sec preferred_lft 298sec
2: enp3s0    inet6 fe80::7285:c2ff:fe85:90ac/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0    inet6 fe80::42:b5ff:feaf:a693/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
16: wg0    inet 10.8.0.4/32 scope global wg0\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
28: veth34254e4    inet6 fe80::a88b:72ff:fee2:7c78/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
30: veth5c409c5    inet6 fe80::2cff:8ff:fe14:395e/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
32: vethc18f5bc    inet6 fe80::ecc4:1eff:fedd:b881/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
34: veth125baec    inet6 fe80::20eb:b7ff:feaa:abb/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         kabelbox.local  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp3s0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp3s0
kabelbox.local  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp3s0
```

```
# iptables -t nat -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.3/32 -d 172.17.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.3/32 -d 172.17.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.4/32 -d 172.17.0.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.5/32 -d 172.17.0.5/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:3306
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:3000
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:22
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4:80
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.5:9000
```

Comment: (a) How exactly are you trying to connect to your containers? (b) Are there any rules in your `FORWARD` chain that would prevent the connection? (C) Don't use `iptables -L` to show your iptables configuration, because it may leave out critical information.  Use `iptables -t nat -S`.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to them with the webbrowser and apps on my devices in the vpn.
So instead of using 192.168.0.12:8080 I want to use 10.8.0.4:8080

(Replaced the iptables output)